# Fourier analysis question, orthonormal basis.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I need some help with this exercise:

Given $A>0$, let $L_{A}^2(\mathbb{R})$ the subspace of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ of the functions $f$ that satisfy $\hat{f}=\chi_{[\frac{-A}{2},\frac{A}{2}]}\hat{f}$. Prove that the set:
$\left\{\sqrt{A}\frac{\sin(\pi(At-k))}{\pi(At-k)}/ k\in{\mathbb{Z}}\right\}$
is an orthonormal basis of $L^2_A(\mathbb{R})$.

This is an exercise of a Fourier series course, and I really don't know how to lead with it...
Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Being an orthonormal basis for the subspace means that (1) it's an orthogonal set, (2) every element in the set has norm 1, and (3) it's a basis for the subspace. These three things can be proved separately from one another. Which part are you stuck on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding $\sin(2\pi x)$ yields
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{\pi x}e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{2\pi ix(1-\xi)}-e^{-2\pi ix(1+\xi)}}{2\pi ix}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}
$$
Using the contour, $\gamma$, from $-\infty-i\epsilon$ to $+\infty-i\epsilon$, then circling back counterclockwise through the upper half-plane for positive $\alpha$, or clockwise through the lower half-plane for negative $\alpha$, we  get
$$
\int_\gamma\frac{e^{2\pi ix\alpha}}{2\pi ix}\,\mathrm{d}x
=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
1&\text{if }\alpha\ge0\\
0&\text{if }\alpha\lt0
\end{array}\right.\tag{2}
$$
Thus, using $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{\pi x}e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x
=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
1&\text{if }-1\le\xi\le1\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.\tag{3}
$$
Usual scaling of the Fourier Transform yields
$$
\sqrt{A}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(\pi Ax)}{\pi Ax}e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x
=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
\frac1{\sqrt{A}}&\text{if }-\frac A2\le\xi\le\frac A2\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.\tag{4}
$$
Usual translation of the Fourier Transform yields
$$
\sqrt{A}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(\pi(Ax-k))}{\pi(Ax-k)}e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x
=\left\{\begin{array}{cl}
\frac1{\sqrt{A}}e^{-2\pi i\xi k/A}&\text{if }-\frac A2\le\xi\le\frac A2\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.\tag{5}
$$
By the standard $L^2$ duality of the Fourier Transform, since the functions on the right hand side of $(5)$ are orthonormal basis elements of $L^2\left[-\frac A2,\frac A2\right]$, so are $\sqrt{A}\frac{\sin(\pi(Ax-k))}{\pi(Ax-k)}$ an orthonormal basis of $L_A^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: All clear, robjohn. Thank you very much!!